# Mounting and using a secondary drive

Tags: boot, command-line, mount

First of all I am a beginner. Yes I have researched several articles and done lots of reading about file systems. I am using ubuntu server 18.04. I did successfully download and use gparted and have a 3.64 Tib ext4 partition. I am now at the point where I want to mount the drive and tell it to mount on boot. The drive is going to store zoneminder files. (Yes I successfully installed and have zoneminder running with cameras displaying). I am frustrated because I am having trouble doing something that I think should be simple so I am asking for help please. How do i mount the drive and use it?

Answer (score 0):

First check the available disks and them sizes using for example `lsblk`

```
# lsblk 

NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   2,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop1         7:1    0  12,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop2         7:2    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop3         7:3    0  86,9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop4         7:4    0  86,6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
loop5         7:5    0   1,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop6         7:6    0  14,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop7         7:7    0   140M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop8         7:8    0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop9         7:9    0    21M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop10        7:10   0   3,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
loop11        7:11   0 140,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
sda           8:0    1  29,8G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    1  29,8G  0 part
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  78,1G  0 part
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   800M  0 part
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 397,8G  0 part /
```

Next check UUID (this is universal identifier using to mount disk; device name can change if you attach another drives and reboot; UUID stays the same unless you don't format drive).

```
# lsblk -f    

NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0       squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop1       squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop2       squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop3       squashfs                                               /snap/core/4917
loop4       squashfs                                               /snap/core/4486
loop5       squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop6       squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop7       squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop8       squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop9       squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop10      squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
loop11      squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
sda
└─sda1      ext4              61447b22-3f5c-46a8-b933-48c84c33cd9e
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     SYSTEM   30F9-EC3E                            /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2
├─nvme0n1p3
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     RECOVERY 0A080BEE080BD819
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4              3cbe87ad-807d-45be-9565-d8f941c17b7e /
```

I choose `/dev/sda1` (first partition on `/dev/sda` drive).
First create mounting point, for example `/data`

```
sudo mkdir /data
```

To enable automounting parition you have to chanage `/etc/fstab` file.
Append the line to that file:

```
UUID=61447b22-3f5c-46a8-b933-48c84c33cd9e  /data  ext4  defaults  0  2
```

One-liner to do that:

```
# echo -e "UUID=61447b22-3f5c-46a8-b933-48c84c33cd9e\t/data\text4\tdefaults\t0\t2" | \
    sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

And mount the drive with command:
     sudo mount /data

One-linear details

1. `echo -e` - prints the line to `stdout` with changing `\t` to `tab`
2. `UUID=...` - partition unique identifier
3. `/data` - mount point of partition
4. `ext4` - filesystem on partition - in your situation may be diffrent
5. `defaults` - mount options
6. `The fifth field (fs_freq).

   This  field  is used by dump(8) to determine which filesystems need to 
   be dumped.  Defaults to zero (don't dump) if not present.
7. `The sixth field (fs_passno).`

   This field is used by fsck(8) to determine the order in which 
   filesystem checks  are  done  at boot  time.  The root filesystem 
   should be specified with a fs_passno of 1.  Other filesystems
   should have a fs_passno of 2.  Filesystems within a drive will be
   checked  sequentially,  but filesystems on different drives will be 
   checked at the same time to utilize parallelism avail‐ able in the 
   hardware.  Defaults to zero (don't fsck) if not present.
8. `|` - Redirect standard output to standard input of next command
9. `sudo` - make privilege escalation to root
10. `tee -a file` append standard input to file